# Ramification of primes in ring class fields

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field of discriminant $D_K$, let $n$ be a positive integer. Call $H_n$ the ring class field of $K$ of conductor $n$. Then, all primes of $K$ that do not divide $n$ are unramified in $H_n/K$.

Is it true that all primes of $\mathbb{Q}$ that do not divide $nD_K$ are unramified in the extension $H_n/\mathbb{Q}$?

I was hoping to say yes, but non-ramification is in general not transitive in field extensions...

Comment: Why do you think that non-ramification is not transitive?

Comment: Uh yes, maybe I am just making a big blunder. I was thinking about the existence of towers of Hilbert class fields, and this led me to think that the composite of two unramified extensions is not necessarily unramified. But when I come to a down-to-earth argument, it seems impossible

Comment: But ok, the point in the existence of towers of Hilbert class fields is the following: if $H_2/H_1/K$ is a tower of Hilbert class fields and $H_2\ne H_1$, then $H_2/K$ is no more abelian!